# White spots are appearing across glass

Tags: lighting, glass

[Updated]

Upon further research, it seems my main light is bouncing a single time off of the bulbs and immediately into the camera, causing a reflection of the super-bright light source. How can this be fixed without increasing size? Clamping removes light inside the bulbs, so that isn't working.

[image]

Here is the scene with an alternate light source.
My issue is with the light reflection from the first bounce. 
You see it here as well with the numerous reflections of the filament and the random overbright places in other bulb reflections.

[image]

Comment: Are you using an HDRI as background to light your scene?

Comment: @Carlo I am not.

Comment: The bulbs are projecting a shadows on the plane, so there should be something that emit light. Could you show your outliner set to "Visible Layers"?

Comment: @Carlo Updated.

Comment: Is your Denoiser on? I know for sure that 2.7.9 has that feature, not sure if 78 does. That should fix it, but it's a hack-ish way to do it and isn't necessarily the 'right' way to do it.

Comment: @Akados I can enable it. It's brand new though, and I don't know the specifics of what does what with it. Especially for targeted removal of the white reflections.

Comment: I'm mostly looking to dodge the strange light patterns I'm getting from the first reflection of the light source.